# Django Rest Framework + Django CAS

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've been tasked with adding [CAS authentication](https://djangocas.dev) to an existing Django app which uses the [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org).

Using [django-cas](https://djangocas.dev) library I'm able to authenticate via CAS to the admin features of the Django framework, but I'm not sure how to go about authenticating the Django rest framework app via CAS; it's still authenticating via some custom authentication logic that the original developers added. If anyone has any insight or experience with this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Abishek not yet until now.